# Debugging different projects in VS6

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have 3 projects in a VS6 workspace.

One is the main program, which calls - depending on configuration - one or both other progams. To call the other programs a exe is executed.

If I want to debug and set breakpoints in one of the subsequent programs, I get an error that breakpoints could not be set and have been deactivated.

Are there any VS6 settings I can check?

This is a legacy tool and neither the architecture nor VS6 can be changed. To make things worse I am not very familiar with VS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember exactly the behavior of VC6, but i think you can start 3 instances of Visual Studio, each containing one of the projects (you'll have to create 3 different workspaces). Within each instance you can debug one program. This at least worked with later Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: This is how I work with VS6.0 in WinXP and WinServer2K3.

Answer (score 1):

A common reason for that error is if you have set one or more of the components to build in Release mode. Make sure that they're all set to build in Debug mode.

Can't remember where those settings are I'm afraid, but I think they're fairly easy to find (under some project menu?).

Comment: I am quite sure I call the debug executable, but I will check.

Comment: @Simon: Sorry, I just read through your question again and I think I misunderstood it before. You actually have 3 executables, correct? If so, I think (it's too long ago so this is really just a guess) that you can't set a breakpoint in any except the one that starts up since the symbols won't be loaded for the other executables. One way to get around this is to start debugging the first exe and then when it's started one of the others you attach a debugger (a separate VS instance) to that process.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. 
Thanks for your hints :)


For me this architecture design is quite strange, but as already mentioned, I can't change it.